# Why does changing this regex class to .+ not provide any match?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

If I use this

```
string showPattern = @"return new_lightox\(this\);"">[a-zA-Z0-9(\s),!\?\-:'&%]+</a>";
MatchCollection showMatches = Regex.Matches(pageSource, showPattern);
```

I get some matches but I want to get rid of `[a-zA-Z0-9(\s),!\?\-:'&%]+`and use any char `.+`
but if do this I get no match at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you make the title of the question a bit more descriptive? Now the answers can't be found by others that need them.

Comment: I've attempted a better title, but if anyone has something better go ahead and change it... ah, looks like my edit crossed with Abel's. :)

Comment: @iwein: done, but change it to something better if it isn't clear enough yet. (edit: sorry Peter, we indeed crossed each other. I liked yours better, I changed it back)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To let `.` match newline, turn on SingleLine/DOTALL mode - either using a flag in the function call (as [Abel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227069/another-regex-question/3227103#3227103) shows), or using the inline modifier `(?s)`, like this for the whole expression:

```
"(?s)return new_lightox\(this\);"">.+</a>"
```

Or for just the specific part of it:

```
"return new_lightox\(this\);"">(?s:.+)</a>"
```

It might be better to take that a step further and do this:

```
"return new_lightox\(this\);"">(?s:(?!</?a).+)</a>"
```

Which should prevent the closing `</a>` from belonging to a different link.

However, **you need to be *very* wary here** - it's not clear what you're doing overall, but regex is *not* a good tool for parsing HTML with, and can cause all sorts of problems. **Look at using a HTML DOM parser instead**, such as [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 3):

By default "." does not match newlines, but the class \s does.

Comment: For accuracy, this answer should state that `\s` matches all whitespace, not just newlines.

Answer (score 2):

You're matching a tag, so you probably want something along these lines, instead of `.+`:

```
string showPattern = @"return new_lightox\(this\);"">[^<]+</a>";
```

The reason that the match doesn't hit is possibly because you are missing the [multiline/singleline flag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) and the closing tag is on the next line. In other words, this should work too:

```
// SingleLine option changes the dot (.) to match newlines too
MatchCollection showMatches = Regex.Matches(
                              pageSource, 
                              showPattern, 
                              RegexOptions.SingleLine);
```